# macro memory footprint in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, macros

which one costs more memory?
Macro or global variable?

For ex.

```
#define NAME "subsystem"

const char *name = "subsystem";

And

#define AGE 28
const int age = 28;
```

For those two cases, do they use same memory?
or is global variable size less than macro?

Comment: A macro doesn't cost anything if you don't use it.

Comment: Do you mean `#define AGE 28`?

Comment: yes Alter, that's my typo. I meant #define AGE 28

Comment: Macros that represent constant *values* of some sort rarely make much difference over just directly initializing a variable. Macros that represent *code* (as a sort of inline function or shorthand), however, may have a significant impact, depending on what the code expands to and how often it is used...

Comment: Note that macros in C are essentially "search-replace" done before actual compilation. That is, macros no longer exist when actual data and machine code is generated. So in a way the whole question is meaningless, unless you actually use the macro so it doesn't just vanish at preprosessing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro itself consumes no space whatever in an object file.  It is a shortcut or mnemonic for expressing *source code*.  The memory required by the compiled source code expressed with the help of macros depends on a variety of things, not least the details of the macro definition and the contexts and frequencies of their use.

In your particular example, the global variables consume space in the compiled object file, but the macros do not.  That is an artificial result, however.  Where macros representing values are *used*, the values they represent *do* consume space in the object file.

Comment: if macro is actually used (let's say more than once), will it consume more space than global variables?

Comment: @CBK, multiple use of a macro that expands to a literal value *could* result in a larger executable relative to use of a global variable holding the same value, but it does not necessarily do so.  It depends on the details of the macro's expansion value, the circumstances of its use, and the tool chain used to compile the sources.  In particular, a tool chain that merges identical constants would tend to minimize the cost of macro use, possibly even to *less* than that of comparable use of global variables.

Comment: Also, under some circumstances, a macro's expansion value can be converted directly into a machine code literal that affords use of a cheaper and smaller machine instruction than the one that would be required to operate indirectly on a value stored at some random location in memory (i.e. a variable's value).